# Find the first value bigger than a threshold

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba

This function takes two inputs: `A` is 2D (N,5) while `B` is 1D (N).

It tries to find the smallest `j` such that `A[i,j] > B[i]` for all `i`.

Using numpy with argmax trick is slower than this version where I loop manually through all `i` and compile it with numba. I think the reason why is because as `N` gets much bigger (~60000), it's more expensive to index on the first dimension, rather than to just loop and hoping to stop at small `j`, e.g., `j=2 or j=3`.

Any ideas how to further speed things up?

```
@nb.jit(nb.int64[:](nb.float32[:,:],nb.float32[:]),nopython=True,cache=True)
def find_passed_hz(A, B):
    C = np.empty(len(B), dtype=np.int64)
    _, m = A.shape # m=5
    n = len(current_times)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if A[i,j] > B[i]:
                C[i] = j
                break
    return C
```

NOTE:  every row of `A` is sorted in ascending order, but because `m=5` very small for numpy search_sorted or binary search to have any effect (or not? I tried but it seems to have no effect).

Comment: (Down-voters please comment what in particular makes a post *not useful*.)

Comment: *smallest `j` such that…* is such a `j` guaranteed to exist?

Comment: *find the smallest `j` such that `A[i,j] > B[i]` for all `i`* is not what I see the code do: *return a NumPy array `C` of smallest elements of `A[i,j]` exceeding `B[i]` for **each** `i`*.

Comment: `j` guaranteed to exist, because I set `A[i,4]` very big. for the second comment, yes, that's what I meant. can you suggest the better wordings to be more specific? or I simply insert your second comment in the question? Thank you.

Comment: @greybeard I suspect the variable names and very brief, technical description of the problem may have something to do with it.

Comment: Code this terse is not ready for public consumption, those days are 20 years past. A good explanation would help getting reviews.

Comment: @Mast , thank you for the input. However, this really is all that I need. Should I add the main function to call it, so that it can be run by everybody immediately (will it make the question fit the standard?)

Comment: Adding the main function and imports will definitely help. Whether it will be enough, I do not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dimension was (N, 4), I'd feel invited to open code a binary search.
(N, 5) is one of the "worst" cases: one more value to check than ideal for a binary search.
Just the same:

```
def find_passed_hz(A, thresholds):   # ToDo: check name is suggestive. Type hints?
    """ Return an array C of 
        smallest elements of A[i, j] exceeding thresholds[i] for each i.
        A[i, j] <= A[i, j + 1]; A[i, 4] is known to exceed thresholds[i].
    """
    
    C = np.empty(len(thresholds), dtype=np.int64)
    n = len(current_times)           # ToDo: explain current_times
    for i in range(n):               # i, threshold in enumerate(thresholds) 
        threshold = thresholds[i]
        if threshold < A[i, 2]:      # A[i, 2] would do: how about A[i, 0/1]?
            if threshold < A[i, 1]:  # A[i, 1] would do: how about A[i, 0]?
                C[i] = A[i, 0 if threshold < A[i, 0] else 1]
            else
                C[i] = A[i, 2]       # known good
        else:
            C[i] = A[i, 3 if threshold < A[i, 3] else 4]
    return C
```

Comment: Never used NumPy/SciPy, search for a helpful function without result.